# Animation not working correctly CSS3

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, animation, css

I've been having CSS3 issues, the animation works in Chrome but doesn't work in Firefox.

The CSS code:

```
.mwhaha {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:98;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    animation: fade-in 2s;
    -moz-animation: fade-in 2s;
    -webkit-animation: fade-in 2s;
}
```

Animation code:

```
@keyframes fade-in
{
    from {
        opacity:0;
        display:block;
    }
    from {
        opacity:1;
        display:block;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fade-in
{
    from {
        opacity:0;
        display:block;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
        display:block;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade-in
{
    from {
        opacity:0;
        display:block;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
        display:block;
    }
}
```

Like i said, the code works in Chrome but doesn't work in Firefox.
I've been trying several other methods to make it work like:

```
@-moz-keyframes fade-in
{
    from {
        background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .0);
        display:block;
    }
    to {
        background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
        display:block;
    }
}
```

But still no result.

Comment: Double use of from in keyframes ?

Comment: Oops, will fix it and try if it works. My bad :)

/EDIT: Still not working

Comment: I copied your code into a web page and the animation effect worked fine. Your problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: I don't think `display` and similar non-animateable values are supported; try only using `background-color`

Answer (score 0):

I've put this in a fiddle and corrected the minor mistakes which imo did not cause a problem. The fiddle works fine in Firefox 35.0 / Mac OSX Yosemite.

http://jsfiddle.net/o3qqeL8k/

Which FF version are you using, on what OS?

```css
@keyframes fade-in {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fade-in {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
.mwhaha {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:98;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    animation: fade-in 2s;
    -moz-animation: fade-in 2s;
    -webkit-animation: fade-in 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="mwhaha"></div>
```